# How not to pass params to every method in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following helper that determine which avatar to use. Two parameters are passed into the helper `user` and `size`.

I since I have multiple definitions within the helper that also leverage on the two parameters. I am wondering if there is a way that I don't need to pass in the same params to every def.

My code is currently like this:

```
module AvatarHelper

    def avatar_path(user, size = 24)
        get_facebook_profile_pic(user,size) || 
        user.identities.try(:first).try(:image) ||
        get_gravatar_path(user,size)
    end

    def get_facebook_profile_pic(user, size)
        url = user.identities.try(:first).try(:image)
        url.try(:concat, "?width=#{size}")
    end

    def get_gravatar_path(user, size)
        request_hash = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(user.email.strip)
        default_image_escape = Rack::Utils.escape(DEFAULT_PROFILE_IMAGE_PATH)
        return "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/#{request_hash}?s=#{size}&d=#{default_image_escape}"
    end

end
```

Comment: I'd say create a class

Comment: feels like you're looking for the presenter/decorator abstraction

Comment: Two questions:  1 - Don't you have `current_user` method already available? Unless you're showing different users' images and not the user who is logged in.  2 - Aren't the sizes predefined somewhere? For example: mini, thumb, medium, large, etc?

Comment: @Surya how would you redo the code? is the current_user accessible in the Helper tho? or should I call `before_action :authenticate_user!` in the helper?

Comment: `current_user` should be accessible in all helpers as they are loaded in `ActionView` class.

Comment: So Helpers are meant to be used for `ActionView` but not Controllers?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class with the instance variables user and size. your instance methods can operate on these instance variables.

```
module Helper
 class Avatar
   def initialize(user, size)
     @user = user
     @size = size
   end

   def test
     // method Impl goes here
   end

   def test1
     // method Impl goes here
   end
 end
end
```